# how can I prevent a factory reset of Samsung android device?

Tags: tablet

The Samsung android table I got for my kid has a "Guest Account" feature that lets anyone in without a password. Kind of defeating the point of the password feature that keeps a 7 year old kid out at bedtime.

so I ran:

```
adb shell settings put global guest_user_enabled 0
```

with a USB cable attached and it worked. Now the guest account is gone. But all the 7 year old has to do is go into setting and do a factory reset and that will go back to

```
adb shell settings put global guest_user_enabled 1
```

Right?

How do I win this password war? I'm older. I have to win.

Comment: I think I found the answer. I have to create a restricted account called "kids" and always hand him the tablet logged into this account which cannot reset the device. But If I ever give it to him logged in as the admin account, he could.

Comment: is this for many uses, multiple programs or just one single application, because if it's one single application, you can use screen pinning to pin an application to the screen for privacy.. this will lock the phone from having access to any other app while pinned ! ... this can be found in Security or privacy settings.....   Else a restricted guest account works best

Comment: I'd say this is a losing war - the kid could always just boot the device into recovery mode and factory reset from there, and that's not something you can prevent with anything software - it isn't even a part of Android OS. Granted, if you log into a Google account prior to that, after the reset he'd be asked to enter the password to that account before using it (FRP), which then requires you to intervene, but this is then a lose-lose situation, where he didn't get to use the tablet but you also get some hassle.